# Get Slug in DetailView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.11

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
]
```

views.py

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'news/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
         context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         response = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/news?identifier=SHOP', auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(
        'xxxx',
        'xxxx'))
         context['articleList'] = response.json()
         return context
```

Urls to visit: http://localhost:8000/news/SHOP/

So what my app has to do is, depending on the URL retrieve the slug and use the API of Intrinio to get a response.

The response part all works, but currently its always the same company (?identifier=SHOP). I want to make it dynamic depending on the url.

But im very new to Django and im not sure how I should pass the slug to the DetailView. I hope you can help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the slug in `self.kwargs`.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
     context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     slug = self.kwargs['slug']
     response = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/news?identifier=%s' % slug,
     ...
     )
```

Comment: Great that works! I need to look more I into the kwargs, seems nice